# How to print the weights of Keras embedding?

Tags: keras, gensim

import gensim

Load Google's pre-trained Word2Vec model.

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

embed = model.get_keras_embedding()

print(embed.weights)
```

output: []

How to print the weights of embedding layer in Keras, currently it is printing empty list?